# Cannot get colors right in the function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *

reset()
setworldcoordinates(0, 500, 600, 0)

def rectangle(a, b, c, d, pen_color, fill_color, pensize):
    up()
    setpos (a,b)
    down()
    fd (c-a)
    left(90)
    fd(d-b)
    left (90)
    fd (c-a)
    left (90)
    fd (d-b)
    left(90)

    p = pen_color.strip("pen_color=")
    pen_color(p)
    s = fill_color.strip("fill_color=")
    fill_color(värv2)
    a = pensize.strip("pensize=")
    a = int(a) 
    pensize(a)


rectangle(10,10,200,100, pen_color="red", fill_color="blue", pensize=3)
```

Problem is that I cannot get those colors in the last line. If I start the program, it won't make the pen_color red and fill_color blue and pensize 3. It stays as normal. Any idea how to get those colors right? How to make that function to read those colors from that last line right? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use the square brackets (the {} button in the text editor) for source code... I would respect the identation and all that

Comment: I've attempted to fix up your indentation; please review, I had to guess where your `rectangle` function ended.

Comment: Please do not jack up the indentation that Martijn provided. Function code is indented by one indent, or 4 spaces ususally.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two calls to `strip` remove the string arguments and remove the whole line with the last `strip`:

```
p = pen_color.strip()
pen_color(p)
s = fill_color.strip()
fill_color(s)
a = int(a) 
pensize(a)
```

This code block has to be before the real drawing is done, direct after the `def rectangle...`

Comment: <code>
def rectangle(a, b, c, d, pen_color, fill_color, pensize):
    p = pen_color.strip()
    pen_color(p)
    s = fill_color.strip()
    fill_color(s)
    a = int(pensize)
    pensize(a)
    up()
    setpos (a,b)
    down()
    fd (c-a)
    left(90)
    fd(d-b)
    left (90)
    fd (c-a)
    left (90)
    fd (d-b)
    left(90)
<\code>

Comment: How to put this in code block?
<code>
def rectangle(a, b, c, d, pen_color, fill_color, pensize):
    p = pen_color.strip()
    pen_color(p)
    s = fill_color.strip()
    fill_color(s)
    a = int(pensize)
    pensize(a)
    up()
    setpos (a,b)
    down()
    fd (c-a)
    left(90)
    fd(d-b)
    left (90)
    fd (c-a)
    left (90)
    fd (d-b)
    left(90)
<\code>
It says str object not callable. 
@halex

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to come down to two problems: a misunderstanding on the OP's part that when you pass named arguments that somehow you had to strip off the name; a design error on the OP's part of wild card importing turtle and then using variables that matched turtle function names and/or incorrect turtle method names.  The revised code:

```
from turtle import *

setworldcoordinates(0, 500, 600, 0)

def rectangle(a, b, c, d, pen_color, fill_color, pen_size):
    pencolor(pen_color)
    fillcolor(fill_color)
    pensize(pen_size)

    up()
    setpos(a, b)
    down()

    begin_fill()
    fd(c - a)
    left(90)
    fd(d - b)
    left(90)
    fd(c - a)
    left(90)
    fd(d - b)
    end_fill()

    left(90)

rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100, pen_color="red", fill_color="blue", pen_size=3)

mainloop()
```