# Definition color help needed

Tags: turtle-graphics

This is my code atm.

```
def rectangle(a, b, c, d, pen_color, fill_color, pensize):
    p = pen_color.strip()
    pen_color(p)
    s = fill_color.strip()
    fill_color(s)
    a = int(pensize)
    pensize(a)
    up()
    setpos (a,b)
    down()
    fd (c-a)
    left(90)
    fd(d-b)
    left (90)
    fd (c-a)
    left (90)
    fd (d-b)
    left(90)
rectangle(10,10,200,100, pen_color="red", fill_color="blue", pensize=3)
```

How to get those colours in last line to work in the definition? I would like to have the pen_color red and fill_color blue but it should be read from the last rectangle line. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is that Python code?   If so, tag it "python"

Comment: your homework hasn't evolved much since yesterday. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848062/cannot-get-colors-right-in-the-function .

Answer (score 0):

There are errors across your program. `pen_color`, `fill_color` and so on are not functions but variables, you can't call them and will get a `TypeError`. It's probably pencolor() and fillcolor(), that you want to use. Incomplete example:

```
import turtle

def rect(a,b,pen_color,fill_color,pen_size):
    rec = turtle.Turtle()
    rec.pen(fillcolor=fill_color, pencolor=pen_color, pensize=pen_size)
    rec.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
          rec.forward(a)
          rec.left(90)
          rec.forward(b)
          rec.left(90)
    rec.end_fill()
rect(100,100, pen_color="red", fill_color="blue", pen_size=3)
```

...so you don't get a F